# For each of the following state whether it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, why or why not.

Tags: linear-algebra

For each of the following state whether it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, why or why not.

All vectors of the form ($0$,$a$,$a^2$)

I know it's not a subspace but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Is $(0,3,3^2)+(0,3,3^2)$ representable as $(0,a,a^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative hint:

$(0,1,1)$ is in the set but $-(0,1,1)$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the definition of a subspace on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace). "If u and v are elements in w, then the sum of u and v are elements in w". Find an u and v where this is not the case.